# Is this ClickOnce web-launch scenario compatible with Windows 11 running TLS1.3

Tags: ssl, webclient, clickonce, windows-11, tls1.3

I don't have a Windows 11 machine to test with yet, and am working remotely, but some users with Windows 11 machines with both TLS1.2 and TLS1.3 enabled, are reporting an **SSL connection closed error** under the following scenario, *while Windows10 machines are having no such issues running TLS1.2*.  I'm waiting for the onsite folks to disable 1.3 and test, but in the meantime, thought I'd ask the question here in case someone has already encountered something similar.

SCENARIO
A desktop Windows application targeting .NET 4.8 is launched via the ClickOnce **publish.htm** mechanism.

Step 1. This step succeeds. On the desktop, Edge is opened via a desktop shortcut that starts in Edge's target folder on the local PC, with the URL of the **publish.htm** file passed as an argument to Edge: `https://intranetserver/foo/bar/publish.htm` Edge fetches the publish.htm file from the intranet web server, and via the ClickOnce mechanism, downloads the program payload from the web server and runs the program on the local PC. NOTE: The desktop machine has the SSL client-side certificate installed in Trusted Certificate Authorities and successfully establishes a secure SSL connection with the intranet web server.  .

Step 2. This step fails. After the desktop program is downloaded and launched on the local PC, it, in turn, attempts to instantiate a WebClient object with the https protocol, and then tries to fetch some additional information from the web server via an `ashx` in a different place on the webserver: `https://intranetserver/bim/bam/fetcher.ashx`.
It is at that point the *SSL connection closed* error is raised on the Windows 11 machines *but not on the Windows 10 machines*: the application, when trying to instantiate the WebClient and open the ashx in a different web app on the server, is *unable to establish a trusted connection*.

It is possible that, with TLS1.3, the first SSL connection established to fetch the publish.htm file is somehow interfering with the application's ability to establish a second SSL connection to a different URL on the same server? Or that TLS1.3 regards that as a nefarious action?